# Dropdown property in AppMaker not working

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to dynamically change the nullItemName property of a Dropdown in Google AppMaker.  However, it seems to be ignoring it.  Here is my code and log results:

```
console.log('DEBUG before nullItemName ' + widget.nullItemName);            
widget.nullItemName = 'test';
console.log('DEBUG after nullItemName ' + widget.nullItemName);

DEBUG before nullItemName No selection
DEBUG before nullItemName test
```

So it appears to work, but the widget still shows "No selection".

Is there something else I have to do?  Or could this be a bug?

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug. I've created an issue to track it.
Thanks for the report.